# Show that if $f(t,x,\varepsilon)$ is differentiable with respect to $\varepsilon$ and $f(t,0,\varepsilon)=0$, then $f$ is lipschitz in $\varepsilon$

Tags: continuity, compactness, lipschitz-functions

Suppose

1. $f(t,x,\varepsilon)$ is bounded and has bounded partial derivatives up to the second order with respect to its arguments, $(t,x, \varepsilon)$,  in a neighborhood of $x=0$.
2. $f(t,0,\varepsilon)=0$ for all $t>0$ and $\varepsilon$, where  $\varepsilon>0$ is a small parameter.

Then I want to show that $$\|f(t,x,\varepsilon)-f(t,x,0)\| \leq L \varepsilon \|x\|$$
where $L>0$ is a constant. In other words, $f$ is Lipschitz with respect to $\varepsilon$, linearly in $x$.

We may not need all of the assumptions stated above. But I think we certainly need $f(t,0,\varepsilon)=0$ and $f$ to be differentiable with respect to $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Since $f$ has bounded partial derivative with respect to its arguments, including $\varepsilon$, then obviously it is Lipschitz in $\varepsilon$, that is $$\|f(t,x,\varepsilon)-f(t,x,0)\| \leq L \varepsilon.$$ But I don't know why $\|x\|$ appears on the right hand side of the inequality.

Comment: Just an idea, but $$||f(t,x,\epsilon)-f(t,x,0)||\leq L\epsilon||x||\iff \frac{||f(t,x,\epsilon)-f(t,x,0)||}{||x||}\leq L\epsilon$$ (for non-zero $x$).  It may be that showing $\partial_x f$ is lipschitz might help.